# Initial Query.orderBy() Parameter has to be the same as the Query.where() fieldPath parameter(s) when an inequality operator is invoked

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I have this code where I am trying to fetch a document from a collection where time is not older than half an hour ago. It fails exactly in the inequality operator.

```
try {
  const HALF_HOUR = 0.1 * 6000 * 6000 / 2;
  const tsToMillis = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis();
  const currenttime = new Date(tsToMillis - HALF_HOUR);

  const myCurrentLoc = location[0]; // my device location
  const latitude = myCurrentLoc.latitude;
  const longitude = myCurrentLoc.longitude;

  const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('chats');
  const query = await geocollection.limit(1).near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: 0.03 });
  query.where('details.time', '>=', currenttime).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          this.fetchAllMessages(documentSnapshot.id);
        }
      });
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error("Error in fetch_messages", error);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Something happened: ", e); // ERROR IS TRIGGERED HERE
}
```

> **C:\MyProjects\BLEConnect\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:180 Something happened:  Error: firebase.firestore().collection().orderBy() Invalid query. Initial Query.orderBy() parameter: g.geohash has to be the same as the Query.where() fieldPath parameter(s): details.time when an inequality operator is invoked**

This error occurred only when invoking inequality operator but not "==" equal operator. Why so? I simply dont get it.

P.S.: the "time" field is added when the geohash has been created, so in the same query:

```
const tsToMillis = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis();
const currenttime = new Date(tsToMillis);
const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('chats');
geocollection.add({
  name: 'Geofirestore',
  uid: device_id,    
  coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude),
  time: currenttime
})
```

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the _actual_ error. I'm having a hard time believing an error would say "Somethign happened". (And if that's the literal error, the firebase folks have some explaining to do)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did but I guess I missed that part somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Firestore documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

The way the *inequality* operators are implemented requires that you order on that field first. For the equality operator Firestore is able to do more on its own, for example combining information from multiple indexes in a so-called zig-zag-merge-join.

Comment: sorry Frank, not sure if I got you. Can you please explain again using my code?

Comment: you mean have an .OrderBy() ...

Comment: @showtime: Read very carefully the title of your question (I have edited in the relevant part of the error message).

Comment: There's not really much more to get than what the error message says: in order to use an inequality operation on your query, you have to have a `orderBy` on that field as the first `orderBy` call for the query. This also means that you can't combine such a condition (or range) with a geo-query, as that already requires `>=` and `<=` operators, and as the quote from the documentation says: all range and inequality operators must be on the same field. If you'd like to learn why, here's a (quite long) talk where I explain how geoqueries are implemented: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your explanation! So, basically I am hopeless in that sense. I cant query by time with Geofirestore

Comment: That is correct: if you watch the video I linked, you'll find why it's already quite magic that you can query by location, which normally would require a range (`>=` etc) condition on both lat and lon, which Firestore can't do. Adding yet an another, unrelated, value to the range query is unfeasible.

Comment: This is misleading and wrong! .where clause works just fine with nearby clause. Here is a query that I use in my code which works:  ´ const query = geocollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: 0.05 })
                  .native.where("created", "<", halfHourOld).orderBy("created", "desc").limit(1); ´

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, pay attention to the ´native´ which extends the native queries of firestore:

```
const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('myCollection');
const query = geocollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: 0.05 })
              .native.where("created", ">", thirty_mins_old).orderBy("created", "desc");
```